# Windows: Display mapped network drives with File.listRoots

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestFileRoots {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(File f : File.listRoots()){
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
   }

}
```

When I start cmd and run this class, all of my drives are listed. When I start cmd as an administrator and I run this, my mapped network drives are not listed.

Also, when I start my server manually and call File.listRoots(), all of my drives are listed. But when I start the server using a service, the network drives are not listed.

How can I always list my network drives? I read I can map the network drive within a service, but that's not an option. The drives are already there and I am not permitted to change something about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mapped drives are user-specific (probably mapped during log-on) and not computer specific. So, when `userA` logs on the drives are mapped. When you start your program as a different user (i.e. as administrator or as a service running as SYSTEM) the mapped drives are not available so you can't access them. Your options are:

- Map the drives again as the new user (i.e. service)
- Run your application in the current user's context
- Access the files you need by the UNC path (i.e. instead of `s:\blah` use `\\server\shared_folder\blah`