# Java, get the list of all available shared folders (at least in windows)

Tags: java, jfilechooser

i'm coding my personal FileChooser from zero, it must have all the functions of a normal JFileChooser, it's almost done but in java i don't know how to get the list of all the current available shared folders (Example Home-Group, Mother-pc .. ). I've already tried with FileSystemView but can't get what i want.

In default JFileChooser launched by the same user i got:
[Default JFileChooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HKp9.png)

This is the interface of my own File-chooser:
[MyFileChooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N2cG.png)

My implementation of File-User use the method File.listRoots(); like this example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestFileRoots {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(File f : File.listRoots()){
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

}
```

but it list only my physical drives.

Comment: It's an accademy project.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. It is considered good practice to show what you have tried to tackle a particular problem rather than only asking people to provide a solution. Ideally in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22230542/6505250

Comment: Thank you, i've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the same trouble i found a solution. You can get the list of all shared folder and much more using:

```
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
for (File root : roots) {
    System.out.println(">"+root);

    for (File subitem : fsv.getFiles(root, false)) {
        System.out.println("\t>" + subitem);
        for(File subsub : fsv.getFiles(subitem, false)) {
            System.out.println("\t\t>" + subsub);
        }
    }
}
```